# Could not start process: failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: mongodb, sockets, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I don't know why today when I decided to start my spring-boot-mongodb-data app, it is raising an error that says:

```html
2016-02-09 10:55:45,103 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.102-0500 Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
2016-02-09 10:55:45,104 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.103-0500 [DataFileSync] warning: --syncdelay 0 is not recommended and can have strange performance
2016-02-09 10:55:45,110 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=820 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Users\murruer\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-660cd841-4d24-4401-bce5-dba125af68a0 64-bit host=PE-LT-152110
2016-02-09 10:55:45,110 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-02-09 10:55:45,110 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2016-02-09 10:55:45,110 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] git version: 5901dbfb49d16eaef6f2c2c50fba534d23ac7f6c
2016-02-09 10:55:45,111 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-02-09 10:55:45,111 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-02-09 10:55:45,111 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.110-0500 [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", http: { enabled: false }, port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "disabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Users\murruer\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-660cd841-4d24-4401-bce5-dba125af68a0", journal: { enabled: false }, preallocDataFiles: false, smallFiles: true, syncPeriodSecs: 0.0 } }
2016-02-09 10:55:45,123 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.123-0500 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
2016-02-09 10:55:45,123 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.123-0500 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file C:\Users\murruer\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-660cd841-4d24-4401-bce5-dba125af68a0\local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,228 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.228-0500 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile C:\Users\murruer\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-660cd841-4d24-4401-bce5-dba125af68a0\local.0, filling with zeroes...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,228 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.228-0500 [FileAllocator] creating directory C:\Users\murruer\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-660cd841-4d24-4401-bce5-dba125af68a0\_tmp
2016-02-09 10:55:45,231 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.231-0500 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile C:\Users\murruer\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-660cd841-4d24-4401-bce5-dba125af68a0\local.0, size: 16MB,  took 0 secs
2016-02-09 10:55:45,231 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.231-0500 [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "local.startup_log" }
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.231-0500 [initandlisten]   added index to empty collection
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.231-0500 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: create { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:37 108ms
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.231-0500 [initandlisten] now exiting
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.231-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,232 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,233 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,233 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,233 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2016-02-09 10:55:45,233 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-02-09 10:55:45,233 INFO  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo - 2016-02-09T10:55:45.232-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
2016-02-09 10:55:45,247 ERROR d.f.e.p.runtime.AbstractProcess - failed to call onAfterProcessStart()
java.io.IOException: Could not start process: failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Maybe you can help me to figure out the problem.

Thank you.

**EDITED**

I have solved the problem running

```html
gradle bootRun
```

Comment: Port 27017 is the default for MongoDB.  Do you have another instance running?  Do you still have this problem when you change the port for the embedded instance?

Comment: Yes, that's the case, another application (might be MongoDB - e.g. a hanging process from a different debug session, or another app - although it's less probable) is listening on port 27017 on your local address. in order to track it down use: `netstat -aon | findstr LISTENING | findstr 27017` and the last record will indicate the PID (then you could use TaskManager in order to get the app name,....).

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Sure when I start my application it is starting a new connection and the command shows me two addresses with the same port one is 0.0.0.0:27017 and the other one is 127.0.0.1:27017. But when killing my app those both remains together.

Comment: So my problem remains.

Comment: running Gradle bootRun Solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

Running

```html
gradle bootRun
```

solved the problem